# How to override magento model service class

Tags: xml, magento

I want to override the next class `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote` with mine `Ec_DiscountRegistration_Model_Service_Quote`

I have some example of config.xml file for model overriding

```
<global>
    <models>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <category>Envato_Catalog_Model_Category</category>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </models>
  </global>
```

what should I substitute in my circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

```
...
     <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <service_quote>Ec_DiscountRegistration_Model_Service_Quote</service_quote>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```